# Select weekdays and weekends from a list of dates

Tags: excel, date

I have been trying to research this question for awhile now. I have a column which has days that are every 3 days. Now out of that column I need to be able to pick the next weekday and weekend and put them into two different columns. I have tried a few functions but nothing even seems to come close to working.

```
**Generated Dates**  |   **Weekdays**  | **Weekends**
      1 March              4 March         1 March
      4 March              7 March
      7 March
```

Comment: Are helper cells amenable? Without using an array formula, I think this can be done with a helper cell and a pivot table.

Comment: You need to specify a **year** to determine if a date like 1 March is a weekday or weekend.

Comment: Two questions: 1) If the next weekday is a weekend, do you want the next day+3 after that? 2) Do you want the "next weekend" or an indicator of whether a date falls on a weekend?

Comment: @Gary's Student: The columns in my actual table do have years just didn't type them in on my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If helper cells are amenable to you, I'd use the following approach (note that you need to have your years included in the dates for this and this also assumes that the dates in the `Generated Dates` column is of the **Date** format):

Assuming first date in `A2`:

```
B2: =TEXT(A2,"dddd")
C2: =IF(OR(B2="Saturday",B2="Sunday"),"Weekend","Weekday")
E2: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$4,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$4=$E$1,ROW($C$1:$C$4)),ROW(1:1)),1),"None follows.")
F2: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$C$4,SMALL(IF($C$1:$C$4=$F$1,ROW($C$1:$C$4)),ROW(1:1)),1),"None follows.")
```

The formulas in `E2` and `F2` are ***array formulas***. Input them using <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag everything as far as you want/need.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: That worked like a champ! Thank you for your help I've spent hours trying to figure it out and you do it in a matter of minutes!

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if it helped you. I must admit it's not as elegant as one would want, but it's very, very straightforward. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following:

- No Helper Columns
- Year = 2014
- If weekend, then print date
- If Next Date= Weekday Then print following weekday
- and that March should look like this:

  ---

  Generated Dates          | Next Weekday |  Weekends
  Saturday, March 01, 2014 | 3/4/2014     | 3/1/2014
  Tuesday, March 04, 2014  | 3/7/2014     |
  Friday, March 07, 2014   | 3/10/2014    |
  Monday, March 10, 2014   | 3/13/2014    |
  Thursday, March 13, 2014 | 3/19/2014    |
  Sunday, March 16, 2014   | 3/19/2014    | 3/16/2014
  Wednesday, March 19, 2014| 3/25/2014    |
  Saturday, March 22, 2014 | 3/25/2014    | 3/22/2014
  Tuesday, March 25, 2014  | 3/28/2014    |
  Friday, March 28, 2014   | 3/31/2014    |
  Monday, March 31, 2014   | 4/3/2014     |

NextWeekday Formula = `=IF(WEEKDAY(A2+3,3)>=5,A2+6,A2+3)`
Weekend Formula = `=IF(WEEKDAY(A2,3)>4,A2,"")`
...Where column A is the list of every third date.